# Typing spaces in Ace Editor results in special characters

Tags: jquery, ace-editor

I've installed ace editor into my site, and although when I tested it in a dev environment , now with the same code I am experiencing typing errors - specifically when hitting space or delete.

When I click space strange characters appear instead. Here is an example of my code and an image of what I am seeing.

```
$(function(){

var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");

});
```

Can anybody help?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turned out that this issue was because I included the script like:

```
<script src="src-min/ace.js"></script>
```

and I should have included the following attributes:

```
<script src="src-min/ace.js" data-ace-base="src" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Same here.. the problem hasn't gone away after adding those attributes.

Comment: Scratch that, you have to do this to EVERY script that Ace requires, not just ace.js.

Comment: @Seiyria, can you explain what you mean about 'every script that ace requires'? I'm using angular ace-ui, and have added the data-ace-base and charset to the script tag, not sure what other scripts ace requires.

Comment: @pedalpete For every theme and programming language script you include, you have to add these attributes to it, otherwise you will have some very funky side-effects. I am using it with knockout though, not angular, so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the

```
charset="utf-8"
```

is the important part.