# Red Spaces in ACE with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, safari, ace-editor

I'm trying to figure out why spaces turn red/invalid (`<span class="ace_invisible ace_invisible_space ace_invalid">·</span>`) in ACE with Chrome and Safari. Everything works correctly with Firefox.

Sample:
http://laktak.github.io/js-graphy/

I already specified `charset="utf-8"` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108641/typing-spaces-in-ace-editor-results-in-special-characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by

```
textarea {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

css rule in graphy.css. Disabling that fixes the issue.